# Is there a set $\mathbb{X}$ such that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{X})$ has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

Is there a set $\mathbb{X}$ such that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{X})$ has a cardinality of $\aleph_0$ ? Give a proof.

As for me, i think no, because $\aleph_0$ is a cardinality of a set of natural numbers, then suposing $\mathbb{X}$ is a set of natural numbers, then $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{X})$ would be $2^{\aleph_0}$, which is equal to $\aleph_1$. Am i right or wrong? Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Using "power" to mean "cardinality" when also talking about power sets is a little confusing.

Comment: I actually meant power of a power set .

Comment: So you are asking if there exists a set $X$ such that $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))=\aleph_0$?  Then why didn't you write it that way?

Comment: No I’m asking if there exists a set X so that  cardinality of (P())=\Aleph0

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}$ is not necessarily equal to $\aleph_1$. This statement is known as the continuum hypothesis and is independent from ZFC.

Comment: "*I actually meant power of a power set*"... "*No I'm asking if there exists a set X so that* **cardinality**..."  Then you *did* mean cardinality... like the first commenter said, and then you seem to have claimed otherwise in your very next comment.  The statement in your post then should read "Is there a set $X$ such that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has a **cardinality** of $\aleph_0$"

Comment: @JMoravitz "Power" is an old term for cardinality (see also "equipollent"/"equipotent"). "Power of a power set" does read oddly now, but the OP's usage is fine. That said, to Peter: it is much more common these days to use the term "cardinality," especially because it lets us avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: Edited since OP clarified what they meant

Comment: @JMoravitz A little bit confusing: l am wondering if there is a set X so that the cardinality of its power set is aleph nought.

Comment: In the end, it seems your question is whether there is a "smaller infinity" than $\aleph_0$.  The answer is no.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, got it! It’s just different in different books

Comment: @QC_QAOA Thanks!

Comment: @Sven-Ole Behrend You wanna say that in thi case i cannot write $2^{\Aleph_0}$ if equal to $\Aleph_1$ ?